# mysql query every n seconds and apply value to class name via jquery/javascript

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am attempting to query a db row every n seconds to see if a value has changed, then based that value I want to build a class that I can apply to a div in my page.

I can currently echo out the slide number, i have this

```
echo("The current slide number is: ".$currentSlideNbr);
```

but am not sure how to query every n seconds and then add .$currentSlideNbr to my class name with jquery

Thanks in advance

Comment: See my answer here, it is almost the same question . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030272/notification-when-new-record-is-added-in-database-php-jquery/9030340#9030340

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648082/ajax-auto-update or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802973/how-to-update-the-page-without-refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a simple javascript example that will trigger every n second(s)

```
    var n = 1000; // 1 sec
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'your url',
            method: 'get',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#someelement").addClass(data);
            }
        });
    }, n);
```

if you want to stop the process at any time you can do

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

not that `data` should only contain the classname you like to add. So not

```
echo("The current slide number is: ".$currentSlideNbr);
```

but

```
echo($currentSlideNbr);
```

Comment: a couple questions,
your url = my database address?
and 
data = .$currentSlideNbr?

Comment: maybe this will help, this is what i am using to query the db currently,
$query = "SELECT slide_nbr FROM `skdemo`.`demo` WHERE demo_name = 'culture';";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$currentSlideNbr = $row[0];
$result->free();

$mysqli->close();

Comment: your url is you php file, which queries the database to echo the slide number